# Where does gedit store the last cursor position?

Tags: gedit

When you open an existing text file in gedit, the cursor starts at the position it was at when you last closed the file. So gedit presumably needs to store a list of inodes and offsets.

I'm curious as to where this information is stored since I can't find it in ~/.config/gedit

Comment: You can see all files opened by `gedit` in your `$HOME` with the command `strace -e trace=open $(type -p gedit) Your_File |&  grep $HOME | egrep -v ENOENT`,

Comment: @muru Good point. I've done so.

Comment: Related (on [unix.se]): [Why text file always opens at the same point I closed it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399870/why-text-file-always-opens-at-the-same-point-i-closed-it)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a file in `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata` which gets touched every time you move the cursor and close gedit. It's a binary file, so not easily interpreted. You can probably understand it better with the [gedit source code](https://github.com/GNOME/gedit/blob/master/gedit/gedit-document.c#L477)

Comment: Thanks. Apparently there are command line tools for working with gvfs. See the edit to my question.

Answer (score 26):

Thanks to the answers/comments above, I now know that the gedit position is saved in the GNOME Virtual File System. In particular, it is in the file `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home`.

There are a bunch of command line tools for working with gvfs.

```
gvfs-cat            gvfs-mkdir          gvfs-rename
gvfs-copy           gvfs-monitor-dir    gvfs-rm
gvfs-info           gvfs-monitor-file   gvfs-save
gvfs-less           gvfs-mount          gvfs-set-attribute
gvfs-ls             gvfs-move           gvfs-trash
gvfs-mime           gvfs-open           gvfs-tree
```

The gedit position can be seen with:

```
gvfs-info FILENAME | grep metadata::gedit-position
```

It can be changed like this:

```
gvfs-set-attribute FILENAME metadata::gedit-position 42
```